# Qt5 GUI Build option is not registering changes

Tags: qt, qt-creator, qt5, qmake

Up until a couple hours ago pressing CTRL+R while in Qt would build and run my code. However something changed that I am unaware of that doesn't commit the changes that I make to the GUI. If I move a button for example then rebuild and run, the application will display its previous location. Something to note however, if I run "qmake && make" in a terminal, then rebuild from the GUI it will work. It's a bit of a hassle to keep doing that and thus a solution would be appreciated.

I'm using Qt5 in a Debian 7.0 based environment

Update: I had to disable shadow build to get it to build properly, but I cannot build in another directory

Comment: Does `Rebuild All` or `Run qmake` work? Which QtCreator are you using?

Comment: Have you resolved this for another directory? Disabling shadow build is a bad idea...